# How to delete one of each set of duplicate values in Excel?

Tags: macos, deduplication, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a spreadsheet that contains many duplicates. Instead of removing all of the duplicates, I would like to remove one of each duplicate. I want to remove one record from each set of duplicates.

Before:

```
a
a
a
a
a
b
b
b
b
c
c
d
d
d
d
```

After:

```
a
a
a
a
b
b
b
c
d
d
d
```

If it helps, I am using a csv that I have exported from Salesforce and I am going to feed into the Apex Data Loader in order to delete duplicate records in Salesforce. That's why I need to remove one from each set of duplicates in Excel, so that I don't delete all of my records - just the duplicate values.

I am on a Mac, using Excel Version 15.14

Comment: "Instead of removing all of the duplicates, I would like to remove all of the unique values" does not make sense when looking at before and after. There are "no" unique values in the before data.

Comment: @DavidPostill You're right. What I should have said was 'Instead of removing all of the duplicates, I would like to remove one of each duplicate'

Comment: I retagged this excel 2016, there is no excel 2015 - the 15.14 is 2016.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mimi,

You can accomplish this using an assisting column to produce values for the first duplicate found. You can add one more filter to ensure that the values found have duplicates. Once you have this list, simply sort, and delete those values. The results will be the same as before minus one value for each duplicate:

[image]

Comment: @MimiSakarett No problem at all!